# Tem como usar um imagecopyresampled e um imagecopymerge ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php

Consegui setar o tamanho fixo para a imagem(500x500) agora queria saber se tem como pegar essa imagem ja definida e colocar outra por cima com o imagecopymerge?

```
<?php

$img = $_POST['img'];
$user = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$mask = imagecreatefromgif('imgs/logo.gif');
$width = 500;
$height = 500;
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($img);
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
      $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
   } else {
      $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
   }
$imagem = imagecopymerge($user, $mask, 0,0,0,0,500,500,50);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $user, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image_p);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, tem como.

Digamos que você tenha essa sua imagem resultado do `imagecopyresampled` na variável `$minhaImagem`, você pode utiliza-la `$dst_im` do `imagecopymerge`

```
imagecopymerge ( $minhaImagem , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h , int $pct )
```

Vale lembrar que para trabalhar com imagens deve-se utilizar

```
$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']
```

Ao invés de

```
$_POST['img']
```

E seu formulário deve estar com o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Mais informações no [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopymerge.php)

Comment: Então, eu tentei mas dá aquele icone de imagem quebrada, não sei se estou chamando a imagem certa no "imagejpeg(); vou postar o código para facilitar...

Comment: Isso posta o código, adicionalmente o icone de imagem quebrada aparece na imagem de traz ou da frente?

Comment: Não aparece nenhuma imagem quando eu adiciono o imagecopymerge()

Comment: @Bruno da uma olhada na minha resposta, provavelmente o problema esta no `$_POST['img'];` que deve ser `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Acho que não, pois o [$_POST['img]] vem de um link que o usuario digita no input text, sendo a imagem jpg, não upando nada no servidor...

Comment: Este link é um link relativo `/img/teste.jpg` ou completo `http://teste.com/imagem.jpg`

Comment: Completo... vou editar o código(novamente) fiz uma forma que sobrepõe as duas imagem e depois da um resize pra 500px maaas, eu queria que desse o resize de 500px e depois colocasse a imagem por cima, pois assim a imagem ficaria no centro, por exemplo essa bandeira que o Facebook colocou da frança... sabe? estou tentando fazer em php para estudo...

Comment: Nada ainda....?

Comment: teste `imagecopyresampled($image_p, $user, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagecopymerge($image_p, $mask, 0,0,0,0,500,500,50);`

Comment: Funcionou lol valeu Alan :D